# How to solve Equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to confirm following equations solves to know

```
dϕ = ϕl - ϕ0;
exp1 = (p0 Exp[I ϕ0] + pl Exp[I ϕl])^2 == Icos;
exp2 = (p0 Exp[I ϕ0] + pl Exp[I ϕl] I)^2 == Isin;
exp3 = dϕ = ϕl - ϕ0;
Solve[exp1 && exp2 && exp3, ϕl - ϕ0]
```

however,the output is

```
 {dϕ -> -ϕ0 + ϕl
```

Actually, the answer is

```
dϕ =-arctan[(2Isin-pl^2-p0^2)/(2Icos-pl^2-p0^2)]
```

How can I get the correct result?

Comment: what is `Isin` and `Icos` ? `arctan`? `cos`?  Are these supposed to be trig functions? If so, try with `UpperCase` first letter? Also watch for the missing space between if so. Also, can't solve for `\[Phi]l - \[Phi]0` it has to be single variable you are solving for,

Comment: Isin and Icos are real number ,and arctan is trig function,

Comment: and I have difned dϕ = ϕl - ϕ0, which suposed to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have redundant equations, and wrong syntax. Try this

```
exp1 = (p0 Exp[I ϕ0] + pl Exp[I ϕl])^2 == Icos;
exp2 = (p0 Exp[I ϕ0] + pl Exp[I ϕl] I)^2 == Isin;
Solve[exp1 && exp2, {ϕl, ϕ0}]
```

Comment: I have done it, but got undesirable result, what's wrong with me, please

Comment: @YOUNGHI Add Clear[ϕ0,ϕ1,Icos,Isin,pl,exp1,exp2,p0] before